# How to use raw_input function with if function in Python?

Tags: python

Okay,I am new to programming and trying to make a simple chatterbot program in python. I wrote this code-

```
while (True):
    command = raw_input(shayon)
    if command == "abarjigay":
        print ("Yahoo!")
```

and it is not working. What is the problem?

Comment: 'What' is not working? Does it crash? Does command have a different value? Python error?

Comment: You use `print` as a function but also use `raw_input`. So just to make sure we are on the same page, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: If shayon is defined it should at least run

Comment: It was showing a error that says shayon is not defined.As I changed shayon into a string,the problem solved.

Comment: @RvdK Many thanks for the edit!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
command = raw_input(shayon)
```

The variable `shayon` is not defined before this line, so your program crashes with a `NameError`.

Assign something to `shayon` beforehand, or if you want the actual letter sequence "shayon" to appear to the user as the input prompt, use a string literal.

```
shayon = "what is your favorite color?"
while (True):
    command = raw_input(shayon)
    if command == "abarjigay":
        print ("Yahoo!")
```

or

```
while (True):
    command = raw_input("shayon")
    if command == "abarjigay":
        print ("Yahoo!")
```

Comment: The program worked like a charm after your suggested change. Many thanks :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3 should use the **input** function. See documentation: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/#specification

Comment: I am using python 2.7.6. Thanks anyway :)